# What makes it that I get such a small difference in my algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, return

I've written an algorithm that calculates the maximum amount of water that gets pumped away within a certain time limit. I takes into account the time that you'd have to walk from one station to another and what stations are already pumping water at that time (so a waited graph).

I have around 30 input examples with their correct output and most of them give back a correct answer. However, in some cases, it returns an answer that is 400-800 smaller that what the correct answer is.

I debugged this algorithm down to what it is now, but I can't seem to find the issue here.

This is the algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

/*
First take inputs
Second dijkstra edges between pumping stations
Third dynamic program over the 12 pumping stations
Finally return correct amount

*/

using namespace std;

const int MAXV= 10000;
const int MAXW = 12;
const int MAXE = 30000;
const int MAXT = 20000;
const int INT_MAXT = 20000000;

int Bellman_Ford(int distances[][12], int w, int initial[]){
    int A[w+1][w][3], activatedPumps[w+1][w][w];
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        A[0][i][0] = 0;                 // overall water pumped
        A[0][i][1] = initial[i]-10;     // time left
        A[0][i][2] = 1;                 // number of pumps activated
        activatedPumps [0][i][0] = i;   // the list of activated pumps per 
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= w; i++){
        bool stable = true;
        for (int j=0; j < w; j++){
            bool maxSwitched = false;
            int maximum=j;
            for (int k = 0; k < w; k++){
                bool pumpSwitched = true;
                int Max, Maxt, Try, Tryt;
                for(int l = 0; l < A[i-1][k][2]; l++)
                    if (activatedPumps[i-1][k][l] == j)
                        pumpSwitched = false;
                if (maxSwitched){
                    Max = A[i-1][maximum][0]+(A[i-1][maximum][2]*200) * (distances[maximum][j]+10);
                    Maxt = (A[i-1][maximum][2]+1)*200 *(A[i-1][maximum][1]-distances[maximum][j]-10);
                } else {
                    Max = A[i-1][maximum][0]+(A[i-1][maximum][2]*200) * distances[maximum][j];
                    Maxt = A[i-1][maximum][2]*200 *(A[i-1][maximum][1]-distances[maximum][j]);
                }
                if (pumpSwitched) {
                    Try = A[i-1][k][0]+(A[i-1][k][2]*200)* (distances[k][j]+10);
                    Tryt = (A[i-1][k][2]+1)*200*(A[i-1][k][1]-distances[k][j]-10);
                } else {
                    Try = A[i-1][k][0]+(A[i-1][k][2]*200)* distances[k][j];
                    Tryt = A[i-1][k][2]*200*(A[i-1][k][1]-distances[k][j]);
                }
                if (Max+Maxt < Try+Tryt && (A[i-1][k][1]-distances[k][j] >= 0)){
                    maximum = k;
                    maxSwitched = pumpSwitched;
                }
            }

            if (maximum == j){
                A[i][j][0] = A[i-1][j][0];
                A[i][j][1] = A[i-1][j][1];
                A[i][j][2] = A[i-1][j][2];
                for(int k = 0; k < A[i-1][maximum][2]; k++)
                    activatedPumps[i][j][k] = activatedPumps[i-1][maximum][k];
            } else if (maxSwitched){ 
                A[i][j][0] = (A[i-1][maximum][0] + 
                                ((A[i-1][maximum][2]*200) * distances[maximum][j]) + 
                                (10*A[i-1][maximum][2]*200));
                A[i][j][1] = A[i-1][maximum][1] - distances[maximum][j] - 10;
                A[i][j][2] = A[i-1][maximum][2] + 1;
                for(int k = 0; k < A[i-1][maximum][2]; k++)
                    activatedPumps[i][j][k] = activatedPumps[i-1][maximum][k];
                activatedPumps[i][j][A[i][j][2]-1] = j;
            } else {
                A[i][j][0] = (A[i-1][maximum][0] + 
                                ((A[i-1][maximum][2]*200) * distances[maximum][j]));
                A[i][j][1] = A[i-1][maximum][1] - distances[maximum][j];
                A[i][j][2] = A[i-1][maximum][2];
                for(int k = 0; k < A[i-1][maximum][2]; k++)
                    activatedPumps[i][j][k] = activatedPumps[i-1][maximum][k];
            }
            if (A[i][j][0] != A[i-1][j][0] ||
                A[i][j][1] != A[i-1][j][1] ||
                A[i][j][2] != A[i-1][j][2])
                stable = false;
            
        }
        if (stable){
            int maximum=0;
            for (int k = 0; k < w; k++){
                int Try = A[i][k][0] + A[i][k][1]*A[i][k][2] *200;
                if (maximum < Try)
                maximum = Try;
            }
            return maximum;
        }
    }
    int maximum=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        int Try = A[w][i][0] + A[w][i][1]*A[w][i][2] *200;
        if (maximum < Try)
        maximum = Try;
    }

    return maximum;
}


int dijkstra_stations(int stations[], int v, int distances[][12], int w, int initial[], int t, vector<vector<int>> &edge){
    for (int i = -1; i < w; i++){

        int dist [v+2];
        bool processed[v+2];
        
        for (int j = 1; j <= v; j++){
            dist[j] = INT_MAXT;
            processed[j] = false;
        }  
        if (i == -1)
            dist[1] = 0;
        else
            dist[stations[i]] = 0;

        for (int count = 0; count < v-1; count++){
            int min = INT_MAXT, minIndex=-1;
            for (int j = 1; j <= v; j++){
                if (!processed[j] && dist[j] < min){
                    min = dist[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }
            }

            processed[minIndex] = true;

            for (int j = 1; j <= v; j++){
                //cout << processed[j] << ' ' << edge [minIndex][j] << ' ' << dist [minIndex] << ' ' << dist [j];
                if (minIndex != -1)
                    if (!processed[j] && edge[minIndex][j] <=1000 && dist[minIndex] != INT_MAXT 
                        && dist[minIndex] + edge[minIndex][j] < dist [j])
                        dist[j] = dist[minIndex] + edge[minIndex][j];
            }
        }

        if(i==-1){
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++){
                if (dist[stations[j]] >=0 && dist[stations[j]] <= 1000)
                    initial[j] = t - dist [stations[j]];
                else 
                    count++;
            }
            if (count == w)
                return -1;
        }
        else{
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++){
                distances[i][j] = dist [stations[j]];
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void input_handling(vector<vector<int>> &edge){
    int v, w, e, t;
    cin >> v >> w >> e >> t;
    if (v >= 1 && v <= MAXV && 
        w >= 1 && w <= min(v, MAXW) && 
        e >= 1 && e <= MAXE && 
        t >= 1 && t <= MAXT){

        int stations[MAXW];
        for (int i = 1; i <= v; i++){
            edge [i][i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){
            int num;
            cin >> num;
            stations[i] = num;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < e; i++){
            int ri, ri2, time;
            cin >> ri >> ri2 >> time;
            if (0 <= time && time <= 1000){
                edge[ri][ri2] = time;
                edge[ri2][ri] = time;
            }
        }
        int distances[MAXW][MAXW] , initial[MAXW];
        //std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        if (dijkstra_stations (stations, v, distances, w, initial, t, edge) == -1)
            cout << 0 << '\n';
        else
            cout << Bellman_Ford(distances, w, initial) << '\n';
        /*std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        cout << "Time complexity: ";
        std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - begin;
        cout << duration.count();*/
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> edge;

    std::vector<int> initializeEdge;
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAXV; i++){
        initializeEdge.push_back(1001);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAXV; i++){
        edge.push_back(initializeEdge);
    }

   
    input_handling(edge);

    initializeEdge.clear();
    edge.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

I tried debugging it the same way as before, by giving it the input and looking at the variables at each step. I can't seem to find where it goes wrong now. In comparison to before and relative to how big the numbers are, differences of 400-800 are really hard to find.

Comment: If you have test cases where the algorithm fails, you should include those along with the expected results. To debug, step through one of those cases observing intermediate results until you find the point where they deviate from what is expected. That should show you one place where a bug lies. Fix the bug and repeat until all your test cases work correctly.